# Java : Difficulties trying to store data from MySQL DB into a two-dimensional array of Strings

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

I'm making a game as school project but I'm having trouble getting data out of my database and storing it into my String[][].
The String[][] holds my board elements which are stored in the DB as VARCHAR.
My board table has the following columns: x, y, Icoon, spelbordID, spelID.

This is my code for retreiving the data:

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Connectie.JDBC_URL)) {

        PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM spelbord WHERE spelID = nr AND spelbordID = 1 ");
        ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            x = rs.getInt("x");
            y = rs.getInt("y");
            spelbord[x][y] = rs.getString("Icoon");              
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }

    return spelbord;
```

Whenever I debug, spelbord always shows completely empty.
It worked before when I only had 3 columns (x, y, Icoon) but I had to change it due to needing identifiers per board and game. Since that moment it stopped working.

Comment: `spelID = nr`, are you sure that is correct?

Comment: Yes, nr is a parameter. Sorry I only pasted the actual retreiving code.

Comment: is the value in the psysical column `nr` within the database?

Comment: Where have you declared `spelbord`? EDIT sorry, I reread the question and I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: I guess, is a problem with the query, have you seen in the debugger if the ResultSet has any element?

Comment: spelbord is declared as class variable.

Comment: When I set a breakpoint at the while(rs.next()) line, rs shows Static and Inherited which unfold into lots of things but nothing I can relate to. Then when I want to go to the next step, it jumps to the catch line so I can't itterate through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in the comments, your SQL is incorrect:

```
SELECT * FROM spelbord WHERE spelID = nr AND spelbordID = 1 
                                      ^^
```

`nr` is neither a valid sql identifier nor an id, as the name suggests.
you need to actually put the id in there via [`query.setString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html):

So your updated code would look like this:

```
final String sql = "SELECT x, y, Icoon FROM spelbord WHERE spelID = ? AND spelbordID = ?";

query = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
query.setString(1, your_spel_id);
query.setString(2, your_spel_bord_id);

rs = query.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()) {

}
```